# Limit the CPU usage on windows by using JOB_OBJECT_POST_AT_END_OF_JOB

Tags: windows, winapi

I wanted to limit the CPU usage for my application and for that I am using Job Objects. The basic idea is to use `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_JOB_TIME` and `JOB_OBJECT_POST_AT_END_OF_JOB` to get the notification after 100 milliseconds of CPU time and then take appropriate action. However I am getting notification after 1s or 2s or 3s. There is no consistency in notification. The basic code I have used is as below:

```
jobinfo.jobHandle = CreateJobObject(NULL, jobname);

ZeroMemory(&basicLimit, sizeof(basicLimit));
basicLimit.PriorityClass = NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS;

basicLimit.LimitFlags = JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_JOB_TIME;
/* miliseconds in 100-ns intervals */
basicLimit.PerJobUserTimeLimit.QuadPart = timeinmilisecs * 10000;
SetInformationJobObject(jobinfo.jobHandle, JobObjectBasicLimitInformation,
        &basicLimit, sizeof(basicLimit))

/* Associate end of job action, so that notification can be generated. */
eojInfo.EndOfJobTimeAction = JOB_OBJECT_POST_AT_END_OF_JOB;
if (!SetInformationJobObject(jobinfo.jobHandle, JobObjectEndOfJobTimeInformation,
        &eojInfo, sizeof(eojInfo))
```

After this there is a code to associate I/O port and get notification on a separate thread.
To get the notification, I am using `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` and then after receiving `JOB_OBJECT_MSG_END_OF_JOB_TIME`, again setting the `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_JOB_TIME`.

Could you please let me know why the interrupts/notifications are not occurring at specified intervals?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states that with the flag the system:

> Posts a completion packet to the completion port using the PostQueuedCompletionStatus function. After the completion packet is posted, the system clears the end-of-job time limit, and processes in the job can continue their execution.

I think you can assume the completion packet was posted. That doesn't mean it will be picked up immediately though.

Look what happens next: The processes in the job all continue as if nothing had happened. If one of them is running at a higher priority than the thread which is monitoring the completion port, the monitoring thread will starve and it will take some time for the completion status packet to be read.

You should run that thread at an equal or higher priority than the job task threads to ensure that the completion notification is picked up quickly.

In addition, you should understand that the completion packet is sent once only. After this the limits have been cleared as per the documentation. A further notification only be sent if the limits are reset. In the meantime the processes will continue to run, and no limits will be in place.

You should also know that the notification is not sent based on clock time, it is sent based on ***processor usage***. If the job is using little processor it may take several seconds to use 100ms of processor time. For example if the process is waiting for the disk, for user input, for network activity or for input from other processes, then it will not use the processor and so this time will not count towards the limit.

Comment: I have not set any specific priority for any of the threads (neither for main process thread which does the actual task, nor for monitor thread). However to test the concept, I will try by setting high priority for monitor thread.  Also I am setting the limit again after getting notification.

Comment: @AmitKapila, for the time starting when the notification is *posted*, but before you reset the limit, there is no limit in place. I hope this is clear.

Comment: Yes, I know it. For that reason I have even tried with JOBOBJECT_NOTIFICATION_LIMIT_INFORMATION class where there is no need to reset, but that is also not successful, you can see that in my other posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045172/limit-the-cpu-usage-on-windows-by-using-jobobject-notification-limit-information

Comment: to provide you more information, I have one more observation that lpOverlapped out parameter of GetQueuedCompletionStatus() is always coming NULL, except for first time when the message is JOB_OBJECT_MSG_NEW_PROCESS. The API is always sucessful. As per specs of GetQueuedCompletionStatus(), lpOverlapped should not be NULL.

Comment: You should also know that the notification is not sent based on time, it is sent based on ***processor usage***. If the job is using little processor (for example if it is waiting for the disk) it may take several seconds to use 100ms of processor time.

Comment: Yes, I understand that part. In my job task thread, I am using CPU intensive work, somethink like calculating 10000! (10000 factorial).

Comment: Ben, even after setting the monitor thread priority to highest, the notifications are getting generated after 3 or 4s. I think in windows, there is some minimum time (may be 1s or more) when it checks for CPU usage, though this is not mentioned clearly anywhere. This is based on results and description of parameter RateControlToleranceInterval in JOBOBJECT_NOTIFICATION_LIMIT_INFORMATION class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448386(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @AmitKapila, That is interesting. I think you are correct. It appears that the job quotas are only checked every few seconds or even minutes.  That makes sense from the point of view of the problem which job quotas is intended to solve. To solve your problem, which seems to be different, I suspect you will need to use WMI or the Performance Counters to monitor processor usage, and terminate the processes yourself.