# Limit the CPU usage on windows by using JOBOBJECT_NOTIFICATION_LIMIT_INFORMATION

Tags: winapi

I wanted to limit the CPU usage for my application and for that I am using Job Objects. The basic idea is to use JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_JOB_TIME and JobObjectNotificationLimitInformation class to get the notification after 100 miliseconds of CPU time and then take appropriate action. The basic code I have used is as below:

```
jobinfo.jobHandle = CreateJobObject(NULL, jobname);

ZeroMemory(&notificationLimit, sizeof(notificationLimit));
notificationLimit.LimitFlags = JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_JOB_TIME;
/* miliseconds in 100-ns intervals. here we want notification after 100ms */
notificationLimit.PerJobUserTimeLimit.QuadPart = 100 * 10000;
SetInformationJobObject(jobinfo.jobHandle,JobObjectNotificationLimitInformation,
        &notificationLimit, sizeof(notificationLimit)))

jobinfo.portHandle = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, 1);

portInfo.CompletionKey = jobinfo.jobHandle;
portInfo.CompletionPort = jobinfo.portHandle;
SetInformationJobObject(jobinfo.jobHandle, JobObjectAssociateCompletionPortInformation,
        &portInfo, sizeof(portInfo))

AssignProcessToJobObject(jobinfo.jobHandle, hProc)
```

After this in a separate thread, I used GetQueuedCompletionStatus() and QueryInformationJobObject() to receive the notification. Code to receive notification in a thread is as below:

```
  for(;;)
  {
  DWORD dwNoOfBytes = 0;
  ULONG_PTR ulKey = 0;
  OVERLAPPED* pov = NULL;
  /* Wait for a completion notification.*/

  error = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(
                hPort,         /* Completion port handle */
                &dwNoOfBytes,  /* Bytes transferred */
                &ulKey,
                &pov,          /* OVERLAPPED structure */
                INFINITE       /* Notification time-out interval */
                );
  if (!error)
         printf("error");

  if(pov == NULL)
  {
      error = GetLastError();
      //continue;
  }

  /*
   * Associate actions to job based on notification message
       * and provide a way to exit the loop. Here we can do the handling
   * for the case if flag to disable CPU timer is set.
       */
       if (dwNoOfBytes == JOB_OBJECT_MSG_NOTIFICATION_LIMIT)
   {
    JOBOBJECT_LIMIT_VIOLATION_INFORMATION limitViolation;
    JOBOBJECT_NOTIFICATION_LIMIT_INFORMATION notificationLimit;

    ZeroMemory(&limitViolation, sizeof(limitViolation));
    error = QueryInformationJobObject(hJob,                                         
                                      JobObjectLimitViolationInformation,                                              
                                      &limitViolation, sizeof(limitViolation),
                  NULL);
    if(!error)
    {
        error = GetLastError();
        printf("QueryInformationJobObject failed with errorcode %d", error);
    }
    else if (dwNoOfBytes != JOB_OBJECT_MSG_NEW_PROCESS)
        print("unexpected message received from completion port");
}
```

Here, I am seeing few problems:
a. lpOverlapped in GetQueuedCompletionStatus is always coming as NULL, even though the API is 
   successful and as per specs, this should not be NULL. What could be the reason of same?
b. Notification with message as JOB_OBJECT_MSG_NOTIFICATION_LIMIT is coming even if there is 
   no CPU usage.
c. Notifications are not coming at interval specified which is 100ms.

Comment: Please show the code that you use to issue the query and receive the results.

Comment: I have updated code related to receive of notification in main posting.

Comment: As per the other question, the notification is not sent at any interval. It is sent ***once***. You can reset the limit but it does not apply until you do. Secondly they are not sent based on time, they are sent based on ***processor usage***. If the job is using little processor (for example if it is waiting for the disk) it may take several seconds to use 100ms of processor time.

Comment: The notification is not sent once, it is sent few times, but quite less than expected number of times. For example if I set limit as 100ms, it comes only after 2 or 3 seconds and sometimes more. I have one other concern as well that lpoverlapped parameter in GetQueuedCompletionStatus() is always coming as NULL.